# How to return multiple results in a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

I have a `visitor` table that looks like this:

```
VID    Name      Address        DOB
001    Bob       101 St         03/05/2001
002    James     505 Rd         02/06/1985
003    Jill      201 Place      04/06/1970
```

And a `visits` table that looks like this:

```
VID    Date          Reason
001    05/07/2012    Family
001    06/01/2012    Family
003    03/02/2011    Other
```

I want to do a join query between these two on VID (which I already did) but also have the query show all (multiple) results from visits. So the results would look like:

```
Name         DOB              Visits
Bob          03/05/2001       05/07/2012 Family, 06/01/2012 Family
James        02/06/1985
Jill         04/06/1970       03/02/2011 Other
```

Is this possible? I attempted a subquery like:

> SELECT Name, DOB, (SELECT Date, Reason FROM visits AS H WHERE H.VID=visitor.VID) As Visits FROM visitor;

But that gave me the obvious `Subquery returned more than 1 value` error. The data would be parsed by PHP, but I was hoping to accomplish this in one query.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: @Lieven 2008 R2, added to my question.

Comment: As opposed to de-nomalizing the particular field, another option is to *flatten* the entire result-set and then group by the KEY. (Would be 6 records here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `FOR XML PATH` construct to concatenate your results into one column

```
SELECT   Name
         , DOB
         , STUFF((SELECT ', ' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), H.Date, 101)
                         + ' ' 
                         + H.Reason 
                  FROM   visits AS H 
                  WHERE  H.VID = visitor.VID 
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM     visitor;
```

Note that various date formats are supported with convert. I have used `101` in the example wich translates to `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for all styles supported by convert.

Comment: What about Date? Would that be `Date + ', ' + H.Reason`? Date is a DateTime obj or the sort.

Comment: @JBurace - You will have to cast the date to a string using CONVERT and concatenate that to the reason. I have altered the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to join the two tables and then do the processing in php. So

SELECT a.Name, a.DOB, b.Date, b.Reason FROM visitor a, visits b where a.VID=b.VID order by 1,2 ;

Then you just have to walk through the records and start a new line whenever one of the first two columns changes.

Comment: This is a little to "manual" for my liking (I would just using a grouping operation), but it does avoid de-normalization of the column. A flat result set can quickly become "prohibitively large" for main joins, however..